# Are there Imperial or United States Customary units of electromagnetism, luminous intensity, or moles?

Tags: units, history, si-units

In the UK, Boris Johnson's somewhat beleaguered government has recently [announced](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2022/may/28/boris-johnson-set-to-bring-back-imperial-measurements-to-mark-platinum-jubilee) a consultation on using Brexit to ensure that "more choice can be given to businesses and consumers over the units of measurement they use for trade". In practice, this means that they have opened a [consultation](https://www.gov.uk/government/consultations/choice-on-units-of-measurement-markings-and-sales) (which anyone can fill in) on returning to the use of Imperial units of measure in shops.

I find non-SI units incredibly confusing and, as an experimentalist, have often encountered problems with incompatible standards caused by them.

The fact that this has been brought into the public eye has made me realise that I am aware almost entirely of the fundamental differences between imperial, US customary and SI units of measurement of mass, length, and volume, but **not** the rest of the 7 SI base units.

Other, mostly energy-derived old units are used in odd places – like British Thermal Units, now used almost entirely in the United States, and its various non-identical derived subdivided units, like the flavours of the [therm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therm) and of course the Calorie. Similarly, units of acceleration and force, being derived from mass, length and time, appear quite a lot in the US and North America (e.g. slugs, lb-force, lb-ft, and so on) and admittedly in aviation and military circles. And everyone knows about the unit of temperature, degrees Farenheit, and degrees Rankine, its "sensible" thermodynamic alternative.

So, then, having briefly discussed imperial or US customary variants of mass, length, volume, and temperature, and not needing to worry about time, my question is therefore this: *are there Imperial or US Customary units for electrostatics/electromagnetism, luminous intensity, or the mole*, the remaining SI base units?

I know that within "metric" systems alone electrostatic units are complex - CGS being the famous example – but I know nothing whatsoever about what the Imperial equivalent of a tesla, say, would be (somehow I doubt 2.2 lb per amp-second squared!)

Comment: _"the unit of temperature, Farenheit"_ — unlike kelvin, which an absolute unit (its zero point is at the absolute zero temperature), the Fahrenheit's unit is still a degree: *degree Fahrenheit*, °F. As for your question, the imperial system is a pre-electromagnetic era system. It never included units for electromagnetism. [Here](http://info.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Workshop/advice/coils/unit_systems/) is an overview of electromagnetic unit systems.